# Jquery: how check if an element is visible inside a Boostrap collapsed accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I need to check the visibility on an element inside a Boostrap collapsed accordion.

This element is set to "display:none" under certain circumstances by JQuery Validator, and I need to add some further controls depending on its display settings - as I've encountered a weird behaviour with its functionality in the form I've set and I'm trying to find a different approach.

Obliviously, the problem is that elements inside a collapsed accordion aren't visible, so I don't know how control that property.

The element is:

```
<span id="edit-field-attachments-und-0-upload--2-error" class="error">Campo obbligatorio</span>
```

So, if I try something like to use:

```
$('.panel span.error:visible')
```

or equivalent selectors, I don't get a correct result unless the accordion is opened.

Any idea how solve this situation? Thanks

Comment: try this `$('.panel span.error').is(':visible')`

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work either when the span is inside a collapsed accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, to see if the element exists in the dom as an inline element. If you add style="display: none;" to the span tag to test, you should see that the isVisible will return "none", which you can then add logic to say if the span is inline or none, etc..

```js
function isVisible(el) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(el[0]).display;
}

console.log(isVisible($('#collapse1 .error')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><span id="edit-field-attachments-und-0-upload--2-error" class="error">Campo obbligatorio</span></div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I started from your idea to get the equivalent in Jquery (for coherence with the existent code).

With 

`function isVisible() {
            $('.preventivo-step').each(function () {

                if ($(this).find('span.error').css('display') == 'inline-block') {
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                }

            });
        }`


I got what I needed!